# polynomial function $y(x,w)$ is a linear function of the coefficients $w$

Tags: polynomials

> Although polynomial function $y(x,w)$ is a nonlinear function of $x$, it is a linear function of the coefficients $w$

I came across a phrase like this [here](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/yyang/comp/reading/ridge.pdf).

It might be a simple thing but I don't understand how is it so.

Comment: Informally, each coefficient occurs at a power of exactly $1$. Or, $y(x, \lambda u + \mu v)=\lambda y(x,u) + \mu y(x,v)$.

Comment: so is it like set of linear functions? linear function for each w?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `linear function for each w`. It *is* a linear function in $\,w\,$, which follows pretty much directly from the definition of linearity, if you write down the expressions.

Comment: Sorry I dont have good mathematical foundation. what i want to clarify is that whether i will get a graph like y=mw+c, and if so what is the position of x in the expression.

Comment: It could be thought of as a linear `graph`, but in some higher dimension. Referring back to the linked article, note that $\,w\,$ is an $(M+1)$-dimensional vector. You can write $\,y(x, w)= (1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^M) \cdot (w_0, w_1, w_2, \ldots, w_M)\,$, but that's a vector [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), not the real-number multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$P(x,w_1)=w_{10} + w_{11}x+w_{12}x^2+....w_{1n}x^n$$ and $$P(x,w_2)=w_{20} + w_{21}x+w_{22}x^2+....w_{2n}x^n$$

Then  $$P(x,w_1+w_2)= $$

$$(w_{10}+ w_{20})+( w_{11}+w_{21})x+ (w_{12}+ w_{22}) x^2+....(w_{1n}+w_{2n}) x^n=$$

$$w_{10} + w_{11}x+w_{12}x^2+....w_{1n}x^n +$$

$$w_{20} + w_{21}x+w_{22}x^2+....w_{2n}x^n=$$

$$P(x,w_1)+P(x,w_2)$$

Similarly $$P(x, \lambda w)=\lambda w_0 +\lambda w_1x+\lambda w_2x^2+....\lambda w_nx^n=$$

$$\lambda P(x,  w)$$